# Are check constraints evil?

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is really simple: are sql checks evil? I mean, especially those checks that we can perform on the client.

This is probably the shortest question in History, but its a serious question.

Comment: What is an SQL check? Do you refer to "select from table, check if exists, if not insert" type of check?

Comment: @Mjh http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: They're not evil, per se. Of course, they're purely *decorative* in [tag:mysql] since the engine doesn't enforce them. In other database systems, having a back-stop that you can trust, *no matter* which client (or admin tool) was used to modify the data is usually seen as a good thing, rather than evil.

Comment: Well, I personally *think* it's pointless. Having said that, I think you'll get opinionated answers for this question. You can have an argument that states "why do you check if it's larger than zero if you can have it as unsigned". There could be some use for this for data integrity, but then again - everything has its good and bad sides. The bad side about this is that you have to change table definition if you want to allow for different range of values. Whether that's beneficial for you or not - only you can tell.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by 'evil'?  I think the term is up to interpretation which may make the aswers be opinion based.  Opinion based question & answers are out of topic for Stack Overflow.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check constraints are most definitely *not* evil.

The purpose of constraints is to have the *database* maintain data integrity.  Some aspects of data integrity are maintained by validating the data that goes into columns.  The database is the appropriate place for these checks.

I would argue the opposite, actually.  Data integrity validations *should* be in the database and not at the application layer.  There are certain types of constraints, such as uniqueness, that cannot be easily maintained at the application level.

Answer (score 2):

You mean `CHECK CONSTRAINT` but you have tagged with `MySQL` which doesn't support it. Anyway, check constraint are to validate business constraint before inserting the data to column (example: age has to be less than 100).

Yes it's would be much wise if you can perform the same validation at application layer and once valid then only pass the data to DB layer else throw some validation message to end user. That way, you save the round trip to the DB as well.

Comment: Indeed. Same can be said with unique constraints right? I mean if the application layer is written well enough then many of the constraints can be avoided

Comment: @Asperger, No, not for `unique constraint`. that's for making sure that column holds only unique values. From app layer you may not always make sure about the same. can you?

Comment: yes but it wouldnt be 100% promising.

Comment: I'd say you should still be enforcing these constraints at the database level too (in fact, foremost). Particularly in the case of unique constraints.